# Shopify - Edit HTML

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I would like to edit my Shopify HTML code.

More precisely this :

[image: Code I want to edit.]

But I do not find it in the edit section of the code...

Could you help me to find it please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check the backend theme customizer, and there is any settings to update the title if the theme author product the same

Comment: Otherwise, you need to edit the code of publish theme and find and update the HTML of a particular section under sections tabs.